# Json encode for nested data using PDO PHP

Tags: php, json, pdo

I have following tables:

```
+---------+-----------+      +----------+---------+-------------+
| item_id | item_name |      | image_id | item_id |  image_url  |
+---------+-----------+      +----------+---------+-------------+
|       1 | phone     |      |        1 |       1 | http://url1 |
|       2 | computer  |      |        2 |       1 | http://url2 |
|       3 | keyboard  |      |        3 |       2 | http://url2 |
+---------+-----------+      +----------+---------+-------------+
```

What should I do in php using PDO and json encode to have the following ouput:

```
[
    {
        "item_id":"1",
        "name":"phone",
        "images": [
            {
                "image_id":"1",
                "url":"http://url1"
            },
            {
                "image_id":"2",
                "url":"http://url2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_id":"2",
        "name":"computer",
        "images": [
            {
                "image_id":"3",
                "url":"http://url3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_id":"3",
        "name":"keyboard",
        "images": []
    }
]
```

Do I HAVE to use **foreach** inside **foreach** loop to get this result?

Comment: I only see a need for one `foreach` loop. Get the results with `item_id` and `item_name`. Then you iterate over those. Perform one query per `item_id` and stub the results into the parent array.

Comment: the outer loop I would need to keep track of which item I am currently working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, use a single loop, and a single SQL query.

Firstly the SQL query is

```
SELECT im.image_id, im.image_url, im.item_id
       it.item_name
FROM images im 
   LEFT JOIN items it ON it.item_id=im.item_id
ORDER BY im.item_id, im.image_id
```

And your PHP (paraphrased) is:

```
$lastItemId = -1;
$aJson = array();
while ($row = GetNextRow()) {    // Depends on your class
    $itemID = $row['item_id'];
    if (!isset($aJson[$itemID])) {
        $aJson[$itemID] = array('item_id'=$itemID, 'item_name'=$row['item_name'], images=>array());
    }
    $aJson[$itemID]['images'] = array('image_id'=>$row['image_id'], 'image_url'=>$row['image_url']);

}
echo json_encode($aJson);
```

You should be able to tweak from there?

Comment: Thanks Robbie! I'll try to do it this way in the evening